# IE7/8 won't load ajax content that contains a select box

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have an application that loads, via a jQuery-driven ajax call, a form containing, amongst other things, two select boxes.  The problem is that neither IE7 or 8 load the new content - latest versions of Safari,FF,Opera and Chrome are all OK.

The content loads in IE if the option tags are removed from the select boxes - i.e. IE will load with only the select tags present.

I have checked for CSS issues, HTML issues, and js issues and I can't find anything wrong.

A stripped down version of the page is here: http://wineinf.nzwine.com/dumpthis.asp

Any pointers would be gratefully accepted.

Thanks/Thomas

Comment: It doesn't work with my IE6 as well :(

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the problem was mine.  A closing div tag surplus to requirements was causing the problem.  Apologies for wasted broadband traffic.

Answer (score 1):

No aplogies necessary; you just helped me solve the same problem.

To add to the knowledge here:

1) <script> tags seem to trigger the same behavior, even if there's no code in them

2) IE9 doesn't exhibit this behavior, unless it's in an older document mode